# building solr queries

Tags: performance, solr

Is there a right/wrong way to build queries in solr? Let's say I have two indexed fields, x and y. And a query like `+x:123 +y:abc`. Does the order of the expressions matter (as far as performance is concerned)? For example, if one of the expressions produces a smaller document set than the other, could this impact query performance?

Comment: Did you get your inspiration from RDBMS join optimization problems? Example: you can join **(1)** join 10000 rows in one table to 5 rows in the other or **(2)** join 5 rows in one table to 10000 rows in the other. 

You may have to look closely on lookups on [index data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index)  and [scoring algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model) the way lucene implements it.

Comment: I actually didn't realize there were RDBMS join optimization problems. I was just wondering if the way a query is constructed affects performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think if "+x:123 +y:abc" are being used in a text search parameter there would be no difference in the order. The big performance gains are when you know when to use fq (filter query) vs. q and have caching / commit tuned.

fq is best for non-"text search" fields with a limited list of values (like make, model, type, category, color)

q would be for "text search" so looking for "web developer rockstar" vs "rockstar developer web" will return the same results.

Comment: Use fq for query subsets that are requested often, q for query subsets that are rather 'custom' and change often. Both use different cache configurations that you can adjust. The fq cache obviously is most supporting when the cached fqs are requested over and over again instead of just being cached once and never requested again. Increasing the q cache can be counter productive as too many never again requested q sets are kept and slow down solr. http://lucidworks.com/blog/advanced-filter-caching-in-solr/